# Silent serving of other code based on business logic without redirect

Tags: php

Right now I have an application that can have an old and a new version of code running (2 versions).

Right now in the code I check to make sure they are on the right version of program and if not redirect them to the other url

Examples:

https://example.com/ (Current Version)

https://example.com/PHP-Point-Of-Sale-Prev/ (OLD VERSION)

I want to do the same thing but have all URLS served from https://example.com and it just runs the code from either NEW or OLD without a redirect.

here is what it looks like now.

```
$app_migration_version = $config['migration_version'];
if ($db_migration_version !== NULL && $db_migration_version!=$app_migration_version)
{

    if (!empty($_SERVER))
    {
        $full_url = (is_https() ? 'https' : 'http').('://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    }
    else
    {
        $full_url = 'http://127.0.0.1';
    }
    $prev_folder = isset($_SERVER['CI_PREV_FOLDER']) ?  $_SERVER['CI_PREV_FOLDER'] : 'PHP-Point-Of-Sale-Prev';
    //We are on previous version; redirect to new version
    if (strpos($full_url, $prev_folder) !== FALSE)
    {
            define('SHOULD_BE_ON_NEW',true);
            $new_url = str_replace('/'.$prev_folder, '', $full_url);
    }
    else //We are on new version redirect to old version
    {
        define('SHOULD_BE_ON_OLD',true);
        $url_insertion_point = strpos($full_url, 'index.php') !== FALSE ?  strpos($full_url, 'index.php') : strlen($full_url);
        $new_url = substr_replace($full_url, $prev_folder.'/', $url_insertion_point,0);
    }

    if (!(PHP_SAPI === 'cli' OR defined('STDIN')))
    {
        header('HTTP/1.1 307 Temporary Redirect');
        header('Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate'); // HTTP 1.1.
        header('Pragma: no-cache'); // HTTP 1.0.
        header('Expires: 0'); // Proxies.
        header("Location: $new_url",TRUE,307);
        exit();
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the goal, why would you take care of different code versions in the actual live app?

Comment: I do rollouts to clients in batches in case there are issues not everyone complains. Each client has their own subdomain and database

Comment: Ok, in that case I would assume a sign-up mini-service that is the same for everyone, then a rerouting to the user's subdomain and from there code would be served based on / determined by the authenticated user. Which means I still don't understand your scenario.

Comment: company1.domain.com, company2.domain.com, company3.domain.com/old. In this case company 1 and company 2 are running the latest version while company3 hasn't been upgraded yet

Comment: Yeah, but what's wrong with `if ($user->version == 'old') {//serve old code}`.

Comment: You're using a single point of entry approach, right?

Comment: Single point of entry don’t want url to change. I am using code igniter framework and can modify index.php